# How use on change event in reactjs (hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onchange, setstate

I need to change activeTab by onchange click on tab component.
I think I need use reacts hooks. But I'm still can't understand how it is work.
This code throw error

> 'handleChange is not defined'

```
function TobaccoLine({ match, location  }) {
   const activeTab = useSelector(state => location.state ? location.state.activeTab : 0);

   handleChange = (event, value) => {
      this.setState({ activeTab: value });
   }

    return (
         <div className="userProfile-wrapper">
                     <Tabs
                        value={activeTab}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        variant="scrollable"
                        scrollButtons="off"
                        indicatorColor="primary"
                     >
...
```

Could you please help, because I'm already stuck?
React JS v16+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not class component. The way you're using is public class method. Since, you are using it inside functional component, it is simply a function but the function is not being declared yet. So, you just need to define it:

```
const handleChange = (event, value) => {
  this.setState({ activeTab: value }); // Next problem: See below.
}
```

Earlier, you were getting `handleChange` is `undefined` coz, you were using without `var`,`let` or `const` declaration.

**Next problem:** You're using `this.setState` inside functional component which is not applicable. You'll need to use `useState` hook:

```
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('') // empty initial state, change it
// To set state:
setActiveTab('your value')
// To get state:
console.log(activeTab)
```

If you don't know about hooks, then you can learn more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: Problem two will be: `this.setState` is not a function or something similar. They're going to need to learn the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook to get this working